# Как создать разные robots.txt в режиме Wordpress Мультисайт?

Tags: wordpress

при режиме мультисайт нашел в корне один роботс , как сдклать для каждого домена свой?

Answer (score 1):

> при режиме мультисайт нашел в корне один роботс , как сдклать для
> каждого домена свой?

Нужно использовать SEO-плагины, генерирующие виртуальные и роботс и сайтмап и делающие всё остальное.

Иначе нужно делать разные физ.файлы и реврайтами (в htaccess напр) делать подмену имени файла.

Comment: а как быть с подключением  яндекс метрики и  гугл тег менеджера?

Comment: Это другой вопрос. Но точно также -  подключаешь через плагины.